# Recursive function in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I have the following dataframe created by

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'parent': ['AC1', 'AC2', 'AC3', 'AC1', 'AC11', 'AC5', 'AC5', 'AC6', 'AC8', 'AC9'],
                   'child': ['AC2', 'AC3', 'AC4', 'AC11', 'AC12', 'AC2', 'AC6', 'AC7', 'AC9', 'AC10']})
```

Which outputs the following:

```
    parent  child
0   AC1     AC2
1   AC2     AC3
2   AC3     AC4
3   AC1     AC11
4   AC11    AC12
5   AC5     AC2
6   AC5     AC6
7   AC6     AC7
8   AC8     AC9
9   AC9     AC10
```

I'd like to create a result dataframe where each of the parent (meaning it does not exist in the child column) is listed with the most final child(s).

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'parent': ['AC1', 'AC1', 'AC5', 'AC5', 'AC8', 'AC2'],
                     'child': ['AC4', 'AC12', 'AC4', 'AC7', 'AC10', 'AC4']})
    parent  child
0   AC1     AC4
1   AC1     AC12
2   AC5     AC4
3   AC5     AC7
4   AC8     AC10
5   AC2     AC4
```

I've started the following function but I'm not sure how to complete it.

```
def get_child(df):
result = {}
if df['parent'] not in df['child']:
    return result[df['parent']]
```

Comment: Your expected output seems a bit inconsistent with your description. You define parents as "not existing in the child column", yet AC2 is considered as a parent for the purposes of the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your expected output seems somewhat incongruent with your description (AC2 seems like it shouldn't be considered a parent since it isn't a source node), I'm pretty confident that you want to run a [traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) from each source node to locate all of its leaves. Doing this in the dataframe isn't convenient, so we can use `df.values` and create an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) dictionary to represent the graph. I assume there are no cycles in the graph.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

def find_leaves(graph, src):
    if src in graph:
        for neighbor in graph[src]:
            yield from find_leaves(graph, neighbor)
    else:
        yield src

def pair_sources_to_leaves(df):
    graph = defaultdict(list)
    children = set()

    for parent, child in df.values:
        graph[parent].append(child)
        children.add(child)

    leaves = [[x, list(find_leaves(graph, x))] 
               for x in graph if x not in children]
    return (pd.DataFrame(leaves, columns=df.columns)
              .explode(df.columns[-1])
              .reset_index(drop=True))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "parent": ["AC1", "AC2", "AC3", "AC1", "AC11", 
                   "AC5", "AC5", "AC6", "AC8", "AC9"],
        "child": ["AC2", "AC3", "AC4", "AC11", "AC12", 
                  "AC2", "AC6", "AC7", "AC9", "AC10"]
    })
    print(pair_sources_to_leaves(df))
```

Output:

```
  parent child
0    AC1   AC4
1    AC1  AC12
2    AC5   AC4
3    AC5   AC7
4    AC8  AC10
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, it appears I did make a mistake with AC2. One thing I'm confused about is how to call the function. Do I build my df within it or was that just to show the example.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, exactly. Your input is the hardcoded `df` in main as you show in your question and the result is the final df after building the graph and running the traversals. I've updated the code to make it a little clearer that `pair_sources_to_leaves` makes this transformation as a black box--you may need to add parameters if you expect your columns to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tree structure, a particular type of graph.  A data frame is not a particularly convenient way to represent a tree; I recommend that you switch to `networkx` or some other graph-based package.  Then look up how to do a simple path traversal; you'll find direct support in the graph package documentation.

If you insist on doing this yourself -- which is a reasonable programming exercise -- you just need something like this pseudo-code

```
for each parent not in "child" column:
    here = parent
    while here in parent column:
        here = here["child"]

    record (parent, here) pair
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need the result in a dataframe as I'm join back to other dataframes and possibly writing to Redshift. I will take a look at networkx.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  That's why I gave you the traversal algorithm as well as some search terms.